# How to load html into page without getting Cross Site Request error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a web application on my machine. Here are the relevant parts:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>

    <!--- empty placeholders for external HTML-->
    <div id="welcome"></div>
    <div id="dinnerOverview"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>

    <!-- The application JavaScript code -->
    <script src="js/model/dinnerModel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view/sidebarView.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/sidebarController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/generalController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

js/app.js:

```
$(function() {
    //We instantiate our model
    var model = new DinnerModel();

    // We instantiate the general controller
    var generalController = new GeneralController();
    // And create the instance of the view
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
    var sidebarView = new SideBarView(sidebar, model); 
    //add sidebarView to general controller
    generalController.addView(sidebarView);
    //instantiate sidebar controller
    var sidebarController = new SideController(sidebar, model);

});
```

js/views/sidebarView.js:

```
var SideBarView = function(container, model){
    var container = container;
    var model = model;

    container.load("sidebar.html");
}
```

I get an error for that last line:

```
jquery.js:9631 Failed to load file:///Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/dinnerplanner-html/sidebar.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

What to do about this? I don't see how this is even a cross origin request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the error by hosting a server with my files.

1. Create package.json in the project directory and paste this inside of it:

   `{ 
      "name": "Demo", 
      "version": "1.0.0", 
      "description": "demo project.", 
      "scripts": { 
        "lite": "lite-server --port 10001", 
        "start": "npm run lite" 
      }, 
      "author": "", 
      "license": "ISC", 
      "devDependencies": { 
        "lite-server": "^1.3.1" 
      } 
   }`
2. Step inside of the folder with the terminal and run `npm install`.
3. Run `npm start`.

Now the project can be accessed at `localhost:10001`